# How to unit-test an MVC controller action which depends on authentication in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, authentication

I'd like to write (in c#) a unit-test for an MVC controller action which might return one view or the other, depending on whether the request is authenticated. How can this be done?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can mock your Request. Something like this ([Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) using):

```
var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
request.SetupGet(x => x.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true); // or false

var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
context.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);

var controller = new YourController();
controller.ControllerContext = 
       new ControllerContext(context.Object, new RouteData(), controller);

// test

ViewResult viewResult = (ViewResult)controller.SomeAction();

Assert.True(viewResult.ViewName == "ViewForAuthenticatedRequest");
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me - returns the same viewname regardless of true/false

Answer (score 17):

Using mocking and dependency injection.  The following assumes that you're checking that it is authenticated and then accessing the user object to get the user's id.  Uses [RhinoMocks](http://ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx).

```
// mock context variables
var username = "user";
var httpContext = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpContextBase>();
var request = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpRequestBase>();
var identity = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IIdentity>();
var principal = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IPrincipal>();

httpContext.Expect( c => c.Request ).Return( request ).Repeat.AtLeastOnce();
request.Expect( r => r.IsAuthenticated ).Return( true ).Repeat.AtLeastOnce();
httpContext.Expect( c => c.User ).Return( principal ).Repeat.AtLeastOnce();
principal.Expect( p => p.Identity ).Return( identity ).Repeat.AtLeastOnce();
identity.Expect( i => i.Name ).Return( username ).Repeat.AtLeastOnce();

var controller = new MyController();
// inject context
controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext( httpContext,
                                                      new RouteData(),
                                                      controller );

var result = controller.MyAction() as ViewResult;

Assert.IsNotNull( result );

// verify that expectations were met
identity.VerifyAllExpectations();
principal.VerifyAllExpectations();
request.VerifyAllExpectations();
httpContext.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer which i'm sure is working excellently. since I've tested eu-ge-ne answer (which works fine for me) and he was a little faster with the response, I marked his answer. no offense. have a good day. ;)

Comment: Not a problem.  It's really the same answer.   I only left mine because it shows how to mock the principal/identity in case you need to get at the username -- or the IsInRole method on the principal, which I haven't shown.