# Unit testing an Asp.net MVC controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, controller

I have a controller action that checks

```
this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

What do you suggest how to tackle unit test on such an action?

Comment: Exactly the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106398/how-to-unit-test-an-mvc-controller-action-which-depends-on-authentification-in-c

Comment: thanks eugene... haven't found it before...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest mocking the IsAuthenticated property.  There are a number of other posts on SO about this, you could do a search for them.

Here is an example of mocking the request using Moq:

```
var mockRequest = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
mockRequest.Setup(x => x.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true); 

var mockContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
mockContext.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(mockRequest.Object);

var myController = new MyController();
myController.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(mockContext.Object, new RouteData(), myController);
```

I would highly suggest looking into Scott Hanselman's ubiquitous "MvcMockHelpers" code, which is what I use:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCSessionAtMix08TDDAndMvcMockHelpers.aspx

Comment: But how would you inject your mocked HttpContext/Request? User property is part of Controller class and has it's own code I can't influence.

Comment: Ok. Now your code has the answer. The ControllerContext property I wasn't aware of. Thanks.

Comment: In Moq you are using SetupGet for mocking properties (Setup is only for mocking methods)

Comment: Yes. Or even SetupProperty if it has both setter and getter with "memory"... ;) I know that. womp's code was enough for me to get the concept right.