# Mocking User.Identity in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mocking

I need to create Unit Tests for an ASP.NET MVC 2.0 web site.   The site uses Windows Authentication.

I've been reading up on the necessity to mock the HTTP context for code that deals with the HttpContext.  I feel like I'm starting to get a handle on the DI pattern as well.  (Give the class an attribute of type IRepository and then pass in a Repository object when you instantiate the controller.)

What I don't understand, however, is the proper way to Mock the Windows Principal object available through User.Identity. Is this part of the HttpContext?

Does any body have a link to an article that demonstrates this (or a recommendation for a book)?

Thanks,

Trey Carroll

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I've used IoC to abstract this away with some success.  I first defined a class to represent the currently logged in user:

```
public class CurrentUser
{
    public CurrentUser(IIdentity identity)
    {
        IsAuthenticated = identity.IsAuthenticated;
        DisplayName = identity.Name;

        var formsIdentity = identity as FormsIdentity;

        if (formsIdentity != null)
        {
            UserID = int.Parse(formsIdentity.Ticket.UserData);
        }
    }

    public string DisplayName { get; private set; }
    public bool IsAuthenticated { get; private set; }
    public int UserID { get; private set; }
}
```

It takes an `IIdentity` in the constructor to set its values.  For unit tests, you could add another constructor to allow you bypass the `IIdentity` dependency.

And then I use Ninject (pick your favorite IoC container, doesn't matter), and created a binding for `IIdentity` as such:

```
Bind<IIdentity>().ToMethod(c => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity);
```

Then, inside of my controller I declare the dependency in the constructor:

```
CurrentUser _currentUser;

public HomeController(CurrentUser currentUser)
{
    _currentUser = currentUser;
}
```

The IoC container sees that `HomeController` takes a `CurrentUser` object, and the `CurrentUser` constructor takes an `IIdentity`.  It will resolve the dependencies automatically, and voila!  Your controller can know who the currently logged on user is.  It seems to work pretty well for me with FormsAuthentication.  You might be able to adapt this example to Windows Authentication.

Comment: To me, this method is preferable to mocking controllers and principles and http contexts, etc, as each time I forget exactly which parts I need to mock and have to hunt through other tests to find suitable code to copy and paste.  In my case, the controllers take an ICurrentUserResolver interface, which has a ResolveCurrentUser() method, and the controller never needs to worry about how the current user is determined.

Comment: Thank you @JohnNelson , you saved my life

Answer (score 19):

I don't know for MVC 2.0, but in newer versions you can mock the ControllerContext:

```
// create mock principal
var mocks = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Default);
Mock<IPrincipal> mockPrincipal = mocks.Create<IPrincipal>();
mockPrincipal.SetupGet(p => p.Identity.Name).Returns(userName);
mockPrincipal.Setup(p => p.IsInRole("User")).Returns(true);

// create mock controller context
var mockContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
mockContext.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.User).Returns(mockPrincipal.Object);
mockContext.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);

// create controller
var controller = new MvcController() { ControllerContext = mock.Object };
```

see also [How to unit-test an MVC controller action which depends on authentification in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106398/how-to-unit-test-an-mvc-controller-action-which-depends-on-authentification-in-c)

Answer (score 10):

[Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/) shows [in his blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IPrincipalUserModelBinderInASPNETMVCForEasierTesting.aspx) how to use [IPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.aspx) and ModelBinder to make easier to test the controller by mocking IPrincipal.

Answer (score 5):

**Example for mocking username and SID on MVC4.** 
The username and SID (Windows Authentication) in the following action should be tested:

```
[Authorize]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // get Username
        ViewBag.Username = User.Identity.Name;

        // get SID
        var lIdentity = HttpContext.User.Identity as WindowsIdentity;
        ViewBag.Sid = lIdentity.User.ToString();

        return View();
    }
}
```

I use [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4) and [Visual Studio Test Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.aspx). The test is implemented as follows:

```
[TestMethod]
public void IndexTest()
{
    // Arrange
    var myController = new UserController();
    var contextMock = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
    var httpContextMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    var lWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity("Administrator");

    httpContextMock.Setup(x => x.User).Returns(new WindowsPrincipal(lWindowsIdentity));

    contextMock.Setup(ctx => ctx.HttpContext).Returns(httpContextMock.Object);
    myController.ControllerContext = contextMock.Object;

    // Act
    var lResult = myController.Index() as ViewResult;

    // Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(lResult.ViewBag.Username == "Administrator");
    Assert.IsTrue(lResult.ViewBag.Sid == "Any SID Pattern");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To mock `WindowsIdentity` you can do the following:

```
var mockedPrincipal = new Mock<WindowsPrincipal>(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());

mockedPrincipal.SetupGet(x => x.Identity.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);
mockedPrincipal.SetupGet(x => x.Identity.Name).Returns("Domain\\User1");
mockedPrincipal.Setup(x => x.IsInRole("Domain\\Group1")).Returns(true);
mockedPrincipal.Setup(x => x.IsInRole("Domain\\Group2")).Returns(false);
```

then use `mockedPrincipal.Object` to get the actual `WindowsIdentity`

Answer (score 1):

I've changed dev environment global.asax and Web.Config for use FormsAuth for force a specific user. The username uses the same WindowsAuth format. See:

```
public override void Init()
    {
        base.Init();

        this.PostAuthenticateRequest += 
             new EventHandler(MvcApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest);
    }

    void MvcApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("Domain\\login", true);
    }
```

**The Windows or Forms Auth shares the same login patterns**.

The application will work with both Windows authentication and Form authentication.