# Mock authenticated user using Moq in unit testing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

How we can mock the authenticated user using Moq framework. Form Authentication used.

I need to write unit tests for the action below

```
public PartialViewResult MyGoals()
{
    int userid = ((SocialGoalUser)(User.Identity)).UserId;
    var Goals = goalService.GetMyGoals(userid);
    return PartialView("_MyGoalsView", Goals);
}
```

I need to mock the value for userid here

Comment: Just idle curiosity - have you tried anything yourself before you asked here? What didn't work for you?

Comment: Maybe [similar SO topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027264/mocking-user-identity-in-asp-net-mvc) could help?

Comment: Wehey. Just like I'd have solved it too. Bottom line is, look into topics like dependency injection and inversion of control.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have used something like that, maybe it helps you:

```
var controllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
var principal = new Moq.Mock<IPrincipal>();
principal.Setup(p => p.IsInRole("Administrator")).Returns(true);
principal.SetupGet(x => x.Identity.Name).Returns(userName);
controllerContext.SetupGet(x => x.HttpContext.User).Returns(principal.Object);
controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext.Object;
```

Comment: I do that in a similar way, just without mocking `IPrincipal`:
`contollerContext.Setup(ctx => ctx.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Administrator")).Returns(true);`

Comment: Dotnetcore: For me this ans not working. Pls ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58394501/672891