# ASP MVC Unit Testing GetUserId()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have a controller, where I'm calling a userId:

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

This makes my unit test fail, since User is null.
I've tried to set a user in the test method using this method, but User is still null in the controller when the test runs.

```
var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
var mockIdentity = new Mock<IIdentity>();
context.SetupGet(x => x.User.Identity).Returns(mockIdentity.Object);
mockIdentity.Setup(u => u.Name).Returns("test_userName");
```

Any hints as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HttpContextBase.User` is of type `IPrincipal` and you have not mocked it. That's why it is returning null when you access it in tests. You can mock it as follows

```
var controllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
var principal = new Moq.Mock<IPrincipal>();
principal.Setup(p => p.IsInRole("Administrator")).Returns(true);
principal.SetupGet(x => x.Identity.Name).Returns(userName);
controllerContext.SetupGet(x => x.HttpContext.User).Returns(principal.Object);
controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext.Object;
```

Here is the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579519/mock-authenticated-user-using-moq-in-unit-testing) of this code

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22762338/how-do-i-mock-user-identity-getuserid) post, you can do it like this:

```
public class MyController: Controller
{
    public Func<string> GetUserId; //For testing

    public MyController()
    {
        GetUserId = () => User.Identity.GetUserId();
    }
    //controller actions
}
```

And then instead of caling `User.Identity.GetUserId()` when you want the user, you just call `GetUserId()` and mock out the user id in your test:

```
controller = new MyController()
{
    GetUserId = () => "IdOfYourChoosing"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mocking HttpContextBase but are not passing it to your controller.
Try this pattern:

Class:

```
    public MyClass
    {
        private readonly HttpContextBase _contextBase;

        public MyClass(HttpContextBase contextBase)
        {
            this._contextBase = contextBase;
        }

        public void Process()
        {
            var userId = _contextBase.User.Identity;
        }
    }
```

Test:

```
    [Test]
    public void MyClass_Test_SO()
    {
        // arrange
        var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        var mockIdentity = new Mock<IIdentity>();
        context.SetupGet(x => x.User.Identity).Returns(mockIdentity.Object);
        mockIdentity.Setup(u => u.Name).Returns("test_userName");
        var sut = new MyClass(context.Object);

        // act
        sut.Process();

        // assert
        // ... whatever
    }
```