# How to mock User IPrincipal in Asp.Net Web Forms

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, webforms

I have Asp.Net Web Forms application and I have unit tests for my pages.
How I can mock User in my application? I tried to find the HttpContext on the page, but I could not.

Comment: Are you looking something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579519

Comment: Provide a [mcve] showing what you have tried so far and desired behavior

Comment: Karthik, an example that you gave for MVC, not Web Forms. Web Forms don't contains ControllerContext