# MOQ Unit Test Failing - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

Can someone please help to explain why this is failing?  I think I might tracked it down to having something to do with User.Identity.Name.  It fails at "Act" and I get a System.NullReferenceException. However another method in the same controller does work.

**WORKING TEST**

```
[TestMethod]
public void Home_Index_Returns_ActionResult()
{
    //Arrange
    var mockRepository1 = new Mock<IEditDataRepository>();
    var mockRepository2 = new Mock<IIdentityRepository>();

     mockRepository1
             .Setup(x => x.Edit(It.IsAny<UTCFormViewModel>(), It.IsAny<string>()));
    HomeController controller = new HomeController(mockRepository1.Object, mockRepository2.Object);

    //Act
    ActionResult result = controller.Index();

    //Assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(ActionResult));
}
```

**NOT WORKING TEST** (on a different method)

```
[TestMethod]
public void Edit_Method_Test()
{
    //Arrange
    var mockRepository1 = new Mock<IEditDataRepository>();
    var mockRepository2 = new Mock<IIdentityRepository>();

    mockRepository1
         .Setup(x => x.Edit(It.IsAny<UTCFormViewModel>(), It.IsAny<string>()));

    HomeController controller = new HomeController(mockRepository1.Object, mockRepository2.Object);

    //Act (Fails Here)
    controller.Edit(It.IsAny<UTCFormViewModel>());

    //Assert
    mockRepository1.VerifyAll();
    mockRepository2.VerifyAll();
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
namespace UTC.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller       
    {
        private IEditDataRepository _editDataRepository;
        private IIdentityRepository _identityRepository;

        public HomeController(IEditDataRepository editDataRepository, IIdentityRepository identityRepository )
        {
            _editDataRepository = editDataRepository;
            _identityRepository = identityRepository;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Field1, Field2")] UTCFormViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string fullWindowsUser = User.Identity.Name;
                string windowsUser = _identityRepository.GetWindowsUser(fullWindowsUser);

                _editDataRepository.Edit(model, windowsUser);
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new HttpException(400, "ModelState Invalid");
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

**REPOSITORY**

```
namespace UTC.Repositories
{
    public class IdentityRepository : IIdentityRepository
    {
        public string GetWindowsUser(string fullWindowsUser)
        {
            //Strip off the domain and lower text
            var windowsUser = fullWindowsUser.ToString().ToLower().Split('\\')[1];

            return windowsUser;
        }
    } 
}
```

**REPOSITORY**

```
namespace UTC.Repositories
{
    public class EditDataRepository : IEditDataRepository
    {
        private UTCEntities db = new UTCEntities();

        public void Edit(UTCFormViewModel model, string windowsUser)
        {
            db.ustp_UTCUpdate(windowsUser, model.Field1, model.Field2)

        );
    }        
}
```

Comment: What's the stack trace say?

Comment: I'm just getting this message `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: That's the "message" of the exception. The exception also has a "stacktrace", which will tell you the exact line where it occurred in the controller. Debug the test to inspect it.

Comment: You would be correct about User.Identity.Name. you need to set a fake user for the controller which is null by default unless otherwise setup in the controller context

Comment: You need to mock the user. Refer the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027264/mocking-user-identity-in-asp-net-mvc) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006624/how-to-mock-httpcontext-user-identity-name-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing `User.Identity.Name` but the `User` property of the controller was not setup in your test method hence it will be null when accessed

you will need to set the controller context with a dummy user account. Here is a helper class you can use to mock the `HttpContext` needed to get the user principal.

```cs
private class MockHttpContext : HttpContextBase {
    private readonly IPrincipal user;

    public MockHttpContext(string username, string[] roles = null) {
        var identity = new GenericIdentity(username);
        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, roles ?? new string[] { });
        user = principal;
    }

    public override IPrincipal User {
        get {
            return user;
        }
        set {
            base.User = value;
        }
    }
}
```

in your test after initializing the target controller you would need to set the controller context

```cs
//...other code removed for brevity

var controller = new HomeController(mockRepository1.Object, mockRepository2.Object);

controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext {
    Controller = controller,
    HttpContext = new MockHttpContext("fakeuser@example.com")
};

//...other code removed for brevity
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I'll give a shot and let you know how it goes.  One question though, where would you place that helper class?

Comment: In the test project

Comment: Works great!  Outstanding!  Thank You.