# How to unit-test an action, when return type is ActionResult?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, tdd

I have written unit test for following action.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult/*ViewResult*/ Create(MyViewModel vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Do something...
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(vm);
}
```

Test method can access `Model` properties, only when return type is `ViewResult`. In above code, I have used `RedirectToAction` so return type of this action can not be `ViewResult`.

In such scenario how do you unit-test an action?

Comment: not same, but maybe some clue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106398/how-to-unit-test-an-mvc-controller-action-which-depends-on-authentification-in-c

Answer (score 74, accepted):

So here is my little example:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
  if (1 != id)
  {
    return RedirectToAction("asd");
  }
  return View();
}
```

And the tests:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
  HomeController homeController = new HomeController();
  ActionResult result = homeController.Index(10);
  Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result,typeof(RedirectToRouteResult));
  RedirectToRouteResult routeResult = result as RedirectToRouteResult;
  Assert.AreEqual(routeResult.RouteValues["action"], "asd");
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod2()
{
  HomeController homeController = new HomeController();
  ActionResult result = homeController.Index(1);
  Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(ViewResult));
}
```

**Edit:**
Once you verified that the result type is ViewResut you can cast to it:

```
ViewResult vResult = result as ViewResult;
if(vResult != null)
{
  Assert.IsInstanceOfType(vResult.Model, typeof(YourModelType));
  YourModelType model = vResult.Model as YourModelType;
  if(model != null)
  {
    //...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Please note that

```
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result,typeof(RedirectToRouteResult));
```

has been deprecated.

The new syntax is

```
Assert.That(result, Is.InstanceOf<RedirectToRouteResult>());
```

Comment: Source? looks like Assert.That isn't part of the base unit test. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.aspx are you thinking nunit ?

Comment: I am using visual studio 2015 and it did not work for me

Comment: `Assert.That` is from the [FluentAssertions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentAssertions/) nuget package

Answer (score -2):

Try this code:

```
dynamic result=objectController.Index();
Assert.AreEqual("Index",result.ViewName);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: This code means, to take the dynamic variable and match with the ViewName,in my case the expected ViewName is Index..Its working for me