# testing IActionResult content within vnext application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I have a vnext application in which I add this action :

```
[RoutePrefix("api/[controller]")]
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    public IActionResult generatePasswd(int length)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I added a simple unit test to test this action :

```
[Test]
public void GeneratePasswd_PasswdLength_NewPasswd()
{
    var mockNotifier = new Mock<INotifier>();
    var mockPaswordGenerator = new Mock<IPasswdGenerator>();

    AccountController AccMgr = new AccountController(mockNotifier.Object, mockPaswordGenerator.Object);

    int length = 0;

    IActionResult passwd = AccMgr.generatePasswd(length);

    Assert.IsTrue(passwd is HttpOkResult);     
}
```

I'd like to test the content if `IActionResult` response : **for example** test if its length not zero. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can verify that the returned interface is of a certain type and then cast it to said type, and assert on additional characteristics that you'd expect from it. Consider the following:

```
[Test]
public void GeneratePasswd_PasswdLength_NewPasswd()
{
    var mockNotifier = new Mock<INotifier>();
    var mockPaswordGenerator = new Mock<IPasswdGenerator>();

    var accMgr = new AccountController(mockNotifier.Object, mockPaswordGenerator.Object);

    IActionResult result = accMgr.generatePasswd(length);

    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result , typeof(OkResult));    
}
```

Here was a similar [SO Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865257/how-to-unit-test-an-action-when-return-type-is-actionresult). If you were returning an `IActionResult` that was a view, you could then take the model and perform assertions on it:

```
var vResult = result as ViewResult;
if(vResult != null)
{
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(vResult.Model, typeof(YourModelType));
    var model = vResult.Model as YourModelType;
    if (model != null)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

**Update**

In accordance with the [official documentation](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/controllers/testing.html), you can do something like this:

```
var result = Assert.IsType<HttpOkObjectResult>(controller.generatePasswd(length));
var password = Assert.IsType<string>(result.Value);
```

This would then assume that your implementation of the API would look something like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    public IActionResult generatePasswd(int length)
    {
        // Where the generateImpl returns a string.
        return Ok(generateImpl(length));
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer , but I need to know if the action returns a type other than a view ( like web api controller's actions in the previous version).How can I get its value.for exemple if the return value is string and I need to get its length ?

Comment: There is a nice article on testing controllers here, the first portion is specific to `MVC` views, but the latter half is `Web API` testing http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/controllers/testing.html