# How to unit test session MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, linq-to-twitter

How do I make a unit test for my Index ActionResult to test the view result?

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (!new SessionStateCredentialStore().HasAllCredentials())
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "OAuth");

        return View("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Since in your action you have redirection - one of possible solution is to have Selenium for testing.

Comment: look this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865257/how-to-unit-test-an-action-when-return-type-is-actionresult

Answer (score 0):

That's how your unit test condition should looks:

```
var result = controller.Index();
RedirectToRouteResult routeResult = result as RedirectToRouteResult;
Assert.AreEqual(routeResult.RouteValues["Index"], "OAuth");
```